# Is there a way to run Azure Web App behind Azure API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

Not able to correctly run  sample Python (Flask) web app deployed to Azure App Service with API Management and  . The idea is to have several web apps behind Azure APIM

I deployed a sample Python (Flask) web app to Azure App Service from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-flask-webapp-quickstart

I have it running as https://app-mv.azurewebsites.net/ , but I want to put it behind API Management  and have the app running with API URL suffix. For example as https://app-mv.azurewebsites.net/mv but getting broken UI. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

I'm adding the screenshot with the errors I'm getting while accessing the site from APIM

It should be working like this
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the product to "Unlimited"?

Comment: I tried "unlimited", but it it didn't work

Comment: I guess you can do it with wildcard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually#add-and-test-a-wildcard-operation

You're presenting a Web Application, not an API. Are you sure this is the right service for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Web App behind Azure API management in following ways-

1. You can create an API with the below details in it and then you need to add any operation in the API to access it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. You can directly import it as shown below-

[image]

[image]

In this way, wild card operations will get created for all the common HTTP verbs. Because there is no swagger or OpenAPI files are present for this Python App.

[image]

But you can get expected output by accessing GET operation.

[image]

In order to make the POST call, you can use the APIM URL in Postman because it expects a form-data in the request body which is not yet supported in APIM portal view as per this [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1192704/how-can-have-form-data-option-in-request-body-in-a).

**GET Operation** -

[image]

**POST Operation**-

[image]

3. You can also link the APIM instance from Web App as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I tried everything, but getting 404 for some app resources. I added screenshots to the question

Comment: @MichaelVer you are getting 404 error for the image as it's unable to fetch the image but operation should work as expected